# Linq C#- Get previous element in a collection

Tags: c#, linq, element

Can anyone suggest a query to get previous record in a collection in LINQ.

I've written the below to get next page and it works well. But I'm unable to get the previous element of the list.

```
menu = _applicationContext.RightMenu.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PageOrder > currentPageNo);
```

On using

```
menu = _applicationContext.RightMenu.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PageOrder < currentPageNo);
```

It just displays the first element in the collection and not the preceding element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another way to get the previous element:

```
menu = _applicationContext.RightMenu.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PageOrder == (currentPageNo-1));
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `RightMenu` is in ascending `PageOrder`, you want the last item which is less than `currentPage`.  You need to change `.FirstOrDefault()` to `.LastOrDefault()` for the second line.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it this way:

```
menu = _applicationContext.RightMenu.LastOrDefault(x => x.PageOrder < currentPageNo);
```